# How do I define a separate form template for a multistep form?

Tags: theming, 8, webforms

I have a multistep webform in Drupal 8. I want to define spearate page template for each page in the webform.

I'm trying to define it using hook_theme_suggestions_hook() like below. But how can I identify the current webform page currently viewing from $variables.

```
function custom_module_theme_suggestions_webform(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = array();

  $suggestions[] = 'webform__'.$current_page;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

Comment: in the form itself set $form['#theme'] = 'foo_bar__baz'; and also define the 'foo_bar' theme definition.

Comment: What exactly does "current webform page" refer to in the question - is it the page template or the current route? You can get the current route from `\Drupal::routeMatch()`

Comment: @Alma, In my question "current webform page" means the page which user currently on. It means my webform is a multistep form. I need to identify the current step the user currently on. I have fixed it for time being using D8 temp storage functionality. Adding my answer here for reference.

Comment: If it's a multi-step form then you don't have to jump through the hoops of using the current page, since that can change later on. Using a variable in your request or tempstore as you say is more robust. Then the template suggestions could be based off those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue using D8 temp storage functionality. I was able to get the current step in my form_alter() hook, and I stored it in to a temp variable and accessed it in theme_hook_suggestions() hook().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'mywebform_id') {

    $current_page = $form_state->get('current_page');

    $tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('custom_module');
    $tempstore->set('current_page', $current_page);
  }
}

function custom_module_theme_suggestions_webform(array $variables) {
  $tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('custom_module');
  $current_page = $tempstore->get('current_page');

  $suggestions = array();

  $suggestions[] = 'webform__'.$current_page;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable twig debugging in sites/default/services.yml
If you don't have this file, you must do :

```
cd sites/default
cp default-services.yml services.yml
```

Set debug to true in place of false, in the twig.config section.

Then using Firebug or SHIFT+CTRL+c in chrome you'll be able to identify in the code source of the page the templates suggestions section by section, from page level, to a simple field or block level.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options depending on what your template suggestion varies by - either page route or page path

**Page Route**

```
function custom_module_theme_suggestions_webform(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = array();
  $current_page = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  // Replace non-alphanumeric characters with hyphens.
  $current_page = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($current_page);
  $suggestions[] = 'webform__' . $current_page;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

**Page path / url**

```
function custom_module_theme_suggestions_webform(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = array();
  $current_url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>')->toString();
  $current_page = substr($current_url, strlen(\Drupal::request()->getBaseUrl()))
  // Replace non-alphanumeric characters with hyphens.
  $current_page = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($current_page);
  $suggestions[] = 'webform__' . $current_page;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this method in drupal 9 and webform latest version:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_form_alter().
 */
function module_name_webform_submission_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form['#webform_id'] === 'your_webform_id' && ($current_page = $form_state->get('current_page')) !== '') {
    $form['current_step'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' =>  $current_page,
    ]; 
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function module_name_theme_suggestions_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['form']['#webform_id'] === 'your_webform_id') {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__' . $variables['form']['#webform_id'] . '__' . $variables['form']['current_step']['#value'];
  }
}
```